# When deploying a contract on a custom blockchain using hardhat, i get BroadcastedTxDifferentHash error?

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat, hardhat-deploy

I am trying to deploy a contract to a custom EVM chain using hardhat and i get the following error

`BroadcastedTxDifferentHash: Expected broadcasted transaction to have hash '0x0812eb35f9552c92ff0cdf606a3c871f8087ec864e76194b5192fe22d84a876d', but got '0x63681d32c8fe8a23bdb8462591cf6e1197af6a9e29cf61d36153569bffd1b109'`

**NB: In the vm Sha256 is used for the transaction hash.**

What could be causing this error? Any ideas on how i can resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nice to meet you.

This error seems to occur due to a mismatch between the expected transaction hash and the actual transaction hash. One possible cause could be a discrepancy in the hashing algorithms used.

Firstly, verify whether the SHA256 hash function, as you've mentioned, is correctly implemented and used in your custom EVM.

Secondly, ensure that the transaction data is consistent when deployed and when it is getting hashed. Even a small change in data can result in a drastically different hash.

Thirdly, check the compatibility of your custom EVM chain with Hardhat, as some differences might exist that are causing this issue.

Lastly, if it's possible, consider testing your deployment on a standard EVM chain to see if the problem persists. This can help pinpoint whether the issue lies with the custom EVM or the deployment process itself.

Regards,
Ari